# Filtering out duplicate objects before pushing to an array?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to filter out duplicate objects before pushing each object to an array.

```
function collaborators() {
  var api = '/docs/' + doc_id + '/json';
  $.getJSON(api, {format: "json"} ).done(function(data) {
    var collaborators = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.notes.length; i++) {
      if ( data.notes[i].author === data.notes[i+1].author) {
        console.log('dup found')
        console.log(data.notes[i].author)
      } else {
        collaborators.push(data.notes[i].author);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The console is showing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'author' of undefined". However I am seeing the duplicate entry in `console.log(data.notes[i].author)`, but the array is empty. What needs to be corrected?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last iteration of your loop, there is no `i+1`:

```
data.notes[i+1]
```

Since this is undefined, calling `.author` on it will blow up.  As the error indicates, `data.notes[i+1]` is undefined, therefore there is no property `author` of `undefined`.

Comment: Ah, ok. How is `console.log(data.notes[i].author)` still showing an entry though?

Comment: it executes just fine, right up until the final iteration of the loop.

Comment: @EvanEmolo The `console.log` call using just `i` will always execute just fine, because you have constrained the values of `i` to always be within the bounds of the array indices in your `for` loop declaration. However, when you get to the last value of `i` produced by the `for` loop, attempting to access `i+1` will try to access an array element that is one index farther than the array's maximum index. Some other languages would error there, but JavaScript is more lenient and will give back `undefined`. You then attempt to "dereference" `undefined` with `.author`, which causes the error.